# Run Task Manager as another user (administrator)

Tags: windows, administrator, task-manager, runas

Is it possible to run the Windows Task Manager as another user, for example, as an administrator?

Our users run with limited privileges, so it would be helpful if I could use Task Manager as an administrator to kill a process if needed.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

From the Run prompt (<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd>) type the following and run it:

```
runas /user:Administrator taskmgr
```

Change "Administrator" to whatever user you want to run it as. You will then be prompted to enter the password of that user.

Comment: I just tried using this to kill an instance of svchost.exe that appears to have hung and is taking up 50% CPU time (even with no applications running). I was able to open taskmgr as Administrator but upon attempting to kill the process I still received the error "Unabe to Terminate Process. The operation could not be completed. Access is denied." Anyone understand why? I seem to have no other option but to reboot.

Comment: On some editions of Windows, the administrator account may have to be activated first before this works (cmd.exe run a administrator -> "net user administrator /active:yes") and setting the password ("net user administrator *").

Comment: this works very well with `taskmgr` but it beats me why it is not working with `taskschd.msc` (`Task Scheduler`). I keep getting error  `RUNAS ERROR: Unable to run - c:\Windows\System32\taskschd.msc` `193: c:\Windows\System32\taskschd.msc is not a valid Win32 application.`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 20):

1. Run command prompt as administrator in the right click menu on command prompt icon
2. Type `taskmgr` in the command prompt.

Comment: You can use Shift+Right Click to select "Run as different user"

Answer (score 9):

The simplest way is to create a shortcut on the desktop. You can do this from the User account. In Explorer navigate to:

C:\Windows\System32\taskmgr.exe

Copy and paste to the desktop as a link, or drag and drop whilst holding down .

To use it, right click, runas, and select the desired user/password.

Comment: This worked great for me when the Windows 10 Start Menu stopped working: http://superuser.com/a/1136086/7018

Comment: Note that you can set any shortcut (even a shortcut to a system utility) to always run as Administrator if you do this: 1. Right click on the shortcut, go to properties 2.Under the "Shortcut" tab, click the "Advanced" button. 3. In the "Advanced Properties" window, check "Run as administrator". Now when you double click on the shortcut it will start as admin, (instead of having to right click on the shortcut).

Answer (score 4):

On Windows 7 (and possibly other versions), run task manager (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Esc</kbd>) then at the bottom of the window click `Show processes from all users`. This will run Task Manager with administrator privileges.
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Select the start menu, and type `taskmgr` into the "search programs and file". The task manager should come up in the results. Now right click taskmgr and select "run as administrator".

It works in Windows 7.

Answer (score 2):

Simplest way:

<kbd>Win</kbd> -> Type "taskmgr" -> When it appears on the list press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Comment: I confirm - it works on Windows 10 & 11.

Answer (score 2):

Windows 10:
Win+X -> Windows PowerShell (Admin) -> Type and run "taskmgr".

Windows 11:
Win+X -> Windows Terminal (Admin) -> Type and run "taskmgr".

Answer (score 0):

To Open Task Manager in Admin Mode, I suggest to open command prompt in admin mode first and then type the command for task manager

Open Command Prompt in Admin Mode as Click on Start --> type "Command Prompt" 
(in search program and files field)
Press Shift and Right Click on Command Prompt --> Click on Run as different user
It will ask for login credentials --> Enter Admin Credentials
after opening Command prompt type command --> taskmgr

Comment: Running a command prompt as administrator and then executing `taskmgr` from there is already covered by several other answers, so this answer adds very little

Answer (score 0):

Besides the above, disable in startup - log out and back in to see if anything else comes up in startup via taskmgr.
Disable that log out and back in again.

Once all the Acrobat items have been stopped in Task manager, you can delete the odm.db