# Unable to terminate process

Tags: windows, task-manager, kill

I can't terminate some processes. It says "Access denied". I am the ultimate owner of the computer. How can I terminate such processed anyway?

These are not system processes, these are file managers during file deletion.

Comment: Are you running task manager as Administrator?

Comment: @HackToHell don't know; how to run TM as admin?

Comment: @SuzanCioc [This answer](http://superuser.com/a/199152/50173) shows you how to run it as admin. If you have that, click on *Show processes from all users* and try to end your process again.

Answer (score 5):

Sometimes task manager doesn't kill the process. It's also possible to kill processes from command line with 'taskkill'.

```
taskkill /im process-name /f
taskkill /pid process-id /f
```

It might require to start 'cmd.exe' as Administrator. This can be done at least in Windows 7 by clicking Windows-logo, typing 'cmd.exe', right click the icon that appears, select 'Run as Administrator'.

I've seen also processes that this procedure wasn't able to kill.
[Microsoft documentation of taskkill](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491009.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

When in task manager, on the bottom left is says: (the shield thing)show processes from all users.
Click on that and after, more tasks will appear and then you will be able to delete the task you want!

Comment: You should add some screen shots or more detail to this answer.

Comment: @DrinkSomePimpJuiceIT Or not. This worked for me.

Comment: @WarlikeChimpanzee Congratulations, you are savvy enough to figure it out without pictures! I forgot all about this 2016 comment, thanks for the reminder—this was likely from the review queue anyway so I had to say something so why not suggest a screen shot for "the shield thing"! I still suggest adding the screen shot though just in case others need a visual of the shield thing.